# The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible

Tags: hibernate, logging, slf4j

when i deploy my project i get this error code

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8]
```

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
avr. 30, 2014 10:16:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Infos: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
avr. 30, 2014 10:16:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:285)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:663)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1642)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: I get this error code
I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a comparable error message. I solved it by excluding the dependency `org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-all`. Somehow that jar overrides `org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger`